# I want to reload a plugin in an Eclipse RCP application at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am writing on an Eclipse RCP project with >50 plugins. When changing something on my plugin, I have to take the time to close the RCP App, and run it again. This takes time.

What I'd rather do is to reload the newly-built plugin in question at RCP-runtime. Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Reloading plugins at runtime requires very careful design and implementation, unless you need to do that on the finished product it's probably not worth the effort. Won't running in debug mode cope with the changes you need?

Comment: What exactly is changing?  The plugin.xml file or the code that implements the functionality?  Also, where is this change happening?  In a production install of your RCP or while it's in development?

Comment: @david would there be some solution for when the change happens exclusively in the plugin.xml file ? (I am wondering if I should ask a new question on this with this specific info)

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;

...
// at the place you need to reload your plugin

Platform.getBundle( "bundle " );
```

and replace the String content `"bundle"` with the value from the `MANIFEST.MF` of the `Bundle-SymbolicName:` entry.

Comment: this works for my situation, when only the plugin.xml had changes

Comment: err, scratch that. This works only in some situations (works for deletion of a component, and when readding, but not when adding an entirely new component)